# When is instantaneous velocity equal to average velocity

Tags: calculus, physics, kinematics

Given $s(t) = -t^3 + 2t^2 + \frac32$ be the position of particle moving along $x$ axis at time $t$. At what time will the instantaneous velocity equal the average velocity over the time interval [0,4]?

Instantaneous velocity = $\frac{ds}{dt}= -3t^2 + 4t$

Average velocity = $\frac{s(t)-s(0)}{t} = -t^2 + 2t$

So I need to solve $-3t^2 + 4t =  -t^2 + 2t $ for $t$ right?

Is this correct?

Comment: @PeterForeman average velocity would be $\frac{s(t)-s(0)}{t}?$

Comment: Yes that would be the average velocity over the time interval $[0,t]$. The question itself is unclear because usually you would be provided with a time interval over which the experiment is performed in such questions.

Comment: @PeterForeman I forgot to add the interval, it is $[0,4]$

Comment: @Abhay Then the average velocity is $$\frac{s(4)-s(0)}{4-0}$$

Comment: @PeterForeman thank you, I got it